# Angular 12: how to detect changes of property in service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, angular2-changedetection

My existing project has some dependencies as below. I have one shared service class which holds one shared object "myObject". Lot of components are accessing this shared "SharedService"'s "myObject" and modifying the values.

Problem is that, each component is accessing this "myObject", modifying the values and saving the modified values to server.

Recent task came up to centralize this saving mechanism, whenever "SharedService.myObject"'s values are changed, this centralized saving mechanism will save the values.

```
export class SharedService {
   myObject: MyClass;
}

// This interface is auto generated by API
export interface MyClass {
   id?: number;
   someArray?: Array<SomeOtherInterface>;
   someOtherObject: SomeOtherInterface;
}
```

I tried one solution with 'getter' and 'setter' but setter is not being executed whenever "myObject" values are changed.

```
export class SharedService {
   _myObject: MyClass;
   get myObject() {
     console.log('tracking changes' + JSON.stringify(this._myObject));
   }

   // Setter is not being called upon any change in myObject
   set myObject(myObject: MyClass) {
     console.log('Values changed pre -> ' + JSON.stringify(this._myObject));
     console.log('Values changed new -> ' + JSON.stringify(this.myObject));
   }
}
```

Is there any way, I can track changes in this SharedService itself without modifying all the existing components.

Comment: can you check have you created multiple instance of your service
to create a single instance you must add it to the global app module or providedIn: 'root' on your service

Comment: otherwise you can use behaviorsubject but you have to modify all the components

Comment: "without modifying all the existing components" depends on how you modify the object there. You should add some example code.

Comment: "Setter is not being called upon any change" - setters are called if you set the object like so `myServiceInstance.myObject = { new object }`. Setters are NOT called if you modify the object e.g. `const mo = myServiceInstance.myObject; mo.foo = 'bar'`.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Object are being modified in multiple ways
1. Injecting service into components and directly modifying the values this.myServiceInstance.myObject.id = newId;
2. AppInjector.get(MyService).myObject.id = newId, in some classes.

Comment: @SouhailHARRATI yes I am using @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) on MyService, so I guess only one instance will be used.

Comment: Is myObject a BehaviorSubject?

Comment: @MishaMashina no, myobject is not BehaviorSubject. I should have been but it's not.

Comment: Maybe it would be much easier if it was a BehaviorSubject: when other components/classes call, for example, setValue(newValue) on your service, so you set next as newValue and update server in the same method.

Comment: Please provide a full example that includes exactly how you modify the object and how it's currently saved. Without the exact code, it's impossible to answer the "without modifying all the existing components" part.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this technique.
On Your service :

```
export class SharedService {
   _myObject: MyClass;
   get myObject(): MyClass {
     console.log('tracking changes' + JSON.stringify(this._myObject));
return this._myObject

   }

   // Setter is not being called upon any change in myObject
   set myObject(newSate: MyClass) {
     console.log('Values changed pre -> ' + JSON.stringify(this._myObject));
     console.log('Values changed new -> ' + JSON.stringify(this.myObject));
//new lines
this._myObject = {...this._myObject,...newState}

   }
}
```

Lets suppose You want to change someArray data inside a class has an instance of this service:

```
let someArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let newState : MyClass = {someArray};
//(commit) your new State
this.sharedService.myObject = newState;
```

// If You have a template depend to this state its state will change reactively.

//example all your template variable should to depend to state reference.

Suppose You have ngFor directive use someArray as an array

```
get someArray(){return sharedService.myObject.someArray }
```

get function is a computed function only running when there is a new update;